# How to change style of TextFormField's contextMenu

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

I'm using my custom ThemeData and TextFormField. When I long press the TextFormField, the content of the menu that appears near the TextFormField does not appear. Below are my Custom ThemeData and TextFormField. How can I solve this? What I did wrong ?

[image]
[image]

theme_data_manager.dart

```
import 'package:f_weather/product/init/theme/utility/color_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@immutable
final class ThemeDataManager {
  /// The `darkTheme` getter in the `CustomThemeData` class is returning a `ThemeData` object that defines
  /// the visual appearance of the app when using a dark theme.
  ThemeData get darkTheme {
    return ThemeData(
      useMaterial3: true,
      inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
        ),
        filled: true,
        fillColor: ColorManager.darkSecondaryColor,
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: ColorManager.activeColor,
            width: 2,
          ),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: ColorManager.lightPrimaryColor,
            width: 2,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark().copyWith(
        primary: ColorManager.lightPrimaryColor,
      ),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: ColorManager.darkPrimaryColor,
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        backgroundColor: ColorManager.darkPrimaryColor,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
        selectedItemColor: ColorManager.activeColor,
        backgroundColor: ColorManager.darkSecondaryColor,
        elevation: 10,
      ),
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        titleMedium: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 28,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: ColorManager.lightPrimaryColor,
        ),
        titleSmall: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: ColorManager.lightPrimaryColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// The `lightTheme` getter in the `CustomThemeData` class is returning a `ThemeData` object that
  /// defines the visual appearance of the app when using a light theme.
  ThemeData get lightTheme {
    return ThemeData(
      useMaterial3: true,
      inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
        ),
        filled: true,
        fillColor: ColorManager.lightSecondaryColor,
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: ColorManager.activeColor,
            width: 2,
          ),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: ColorManager.darkSecondaryColor,
            width: 2,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light().copyWith(
        primary: ColorManager.darkPrimaryColor,
      ),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: ColorManager.lightPrimaryColor,
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        backgroundColor: ColorManager.lightPrimaryColor,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
        selectedItemColor: ColorManager.activeColor,
        backgroundColor: ColorManager.lightSecondaryColor,
        elevation: 10,
        selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: ColorManager.darkPrimaryColor,
        ),
      ),
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        titleMedium: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 28,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: ColorManager.darkPrimaryColor,
        ),
        titleSmall: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: ColorManager.darkPrimaryColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

search_text_form_field.dart

```
import 'package:f_weather/product/state/search_places_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mobx/flutter_mobx.dart';

class SearchTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchTextFormField({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;
    double height = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height;

    return SizedBox(
      width: width * 0.9,
      height: height * 0.06,
      child: Observer(
        builder: (context) => TextFormField(
          contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
            return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
              anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
              buttonItems: <ContextMenuButtonItem>[
                ContextMenuButtonItem(
                  onPressed: () {
                    editableTextState.copySelection(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar);
                  },
                  type: ContextMenuButtonType.copy,
                ),
                ContextMenuButtonItem(
                  onPressed: () {
                    editableTextState.selectAll(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar);
                  },
                  type: ContextMenuButtonType.selectAll,
                ),
                ContextMenuButtonItem(
                  onPressed: () {
                    editableTextState.cutSelection(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar);
                  },
                  type: ContextMenuButtonType.cut,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          enableInteractiveSelection: true,
          onChanged: (value) {
            value.isNotEmpty
                ? GetSearchPlacesStateManager.searchPlacesManager.changeClearButtonState(isActive: true)
                : GetSearchPlacesStateManager.searchPlacesManager.changeClearButtonState(isActive: false);
          },
          controller: controller,
          autofocus: true,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
          maxLines: 1,
          autocorrect: false,
          onTapOutside: (_) => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: GetSearchPlacesStateManager.searchPlacesManager.isActiveClearButton
                ? IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.clear();
                      GetSearchPlacesStateManager.searchPlacesManager.changeClearButtonState(isActive: false);
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.clear_outlined),
                  )
                : null,
            hintText: "Search Places",
            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```